# Fedora 27 no hdmi output on AMD card

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, fedora, hdmi

I just bought new laptop with AMD Radeon RX 550M card, installed fresh new Fedora 27 and everything was working properly.

But...

After update (`dnf update`) and restarting laptop my hdmi stopped working.
I dind't install any drivers manually. Do you maybe have any suggestions what might gone wrong?
I provide `lspci` and `xrandr` output:

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5914 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5917 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550] (rev c0)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
05:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
```

`xrandr -q`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
1920x1080     59.96*+
```

What might be worth to mention: I run bios in legacy support mode (not UEFI), graphic card is choosen to be `discrete`.

Comment: I noticed one strange thing:
I enabled UMA only graphic card in bios, then dual screen started to work,
but of course my Radeon card disappeared from `lspci`.
Then I turned `discrete` again and now HDMI works again as before.

Comment: This should considered as an acceptable answer. Thank you!